Red files in libs
All the files in my libs folder in android studio are showing red but the code are error free. I just uninstalled and reinstalled my flutter and I started seeing that
All the files in my lib in android studio are showing red

Try running flutter pub get.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First check if Dart is enabled in your project, by going to Files then select

Settings    =>    Languages & Frameworks    =>    Dart

make should that you are enabling Dart support for the project.
then make "flutter clean" in terminal and "flutter pub get".
